# CSS position issue using LI tag and image slider

Tags: jquery, css, unslider

Am I missing something simple? Can anyone explain why the image is shifted to the right?

The Red border is where the image needs to be, yet it appears that the LI on the unordered list is shifting the images in the slider even with the padding and margin set to zero.

I have tried using `position: relative; left:-40;` but it will cut off the right side of the image unless I use: width:XXpx; I am trying to avoid using a specific width as this will be used in a responsive web design and I want to resize the images based on the size of the device.

Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/vaqdvb5g/

JavaScript files:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.banner li { 
list-style: none; /* Lose the dot */
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.banner ul li { 
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
float: left; 
}

#slider{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" style=""> 
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image: url(http://cdn.nliphonedwwwghan.savviihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/500px1-580x375.jpg); height:350px;"><a href="/testing"></a></li>
        <li style="background-image: url(http://cdn.nliphonedwwwghan.savviihq.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/500px1-580x375.jpg); height:350px;"><a href="testing"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>    
<script>
        // main image settings
        $('.banner').unslider({
                arrows: false,
                delay: 2000,
                fluid: true,
                speed: 1000,
                dots: true
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Reset ul http://jsfiddle.net/vaqdvb5g/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  your CSS code:

```
.banner li { 
list-style: none; /* Lose the dot */
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Should be:

```
.banner ul { 
  list-style: none; /* Lose the dot */
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

The CSS style `list-style` is a styled made for `ul` elements. That is why your slider was off to right a lot. The "dot" was there. Find out more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style)

Comment: That is indeed the issue... Can you please explain why: ".banner ul li {..." did not work?

Comment: @thefid, Yeah I should of done that sooner. I apologize.

Comment: Excellent @King Shimkus! Your answer is even better now. Thanks for your help. My understanding was that ".banner ul li {..." would handle both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the margin as well.  Add this to your stylesheet.

```
.banner ul { 
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```